# Event handler not firing when its caller was invoked in the delegate of a previous event

Tags: c#

**tl;dr**

**Implementing Class:**

```
public Main()
{
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    foo.OnBarOneResponse += foo_OnBarOneResponse;
    foo.OnBarTwoResponse += foo_OnBarTwoResponse;
    foo.FetchBarOne();
}

void foo_OnBarOneResponse(String response)
{
    // Called successfully.
    this.foo.FetchBarTwo();
}

void foo_OnBarTwoResponse(String response)
{
    // Never called :(
}
```

**Foo.cs**

```
private MyJavascriptInjector _javascriptInjector = new MyJavascriptInjector();

public delegate void OnBarOneResponseHandler(String response);
public delegate void OnBarTwoResponseHandler(String response);
public event OnBarOneResponseHandler OnBarOneResponse = delegate { };
public event OnBarTwoResponseHandler OnBarTwoResponse = delegate { };

private void _onBarOneResponse(String response)
{
    // Called Successfully
    OnBarOneResponse(response);
}

private void _onBarTwoResponse(String response)
{
    // Never called :(
    OnBarTwoResponse(response);
}

public Foo() 
{
    webBrowser.ObjectForScripting = _javascriptInjector;
    _javascriptInjector.OnBarOneResponse += _onBarOneResponse;
    _javascriptInjector.OnBarTwoResponse += _onBarTwoResponse;
    webBrowser.Navigate("http://myurl", null, new Byte[0], myHeaders");
}

public void FetchBarOne()
{
    webBrowser.InvokeScript("fetchBarOne");
}

public void FetchBarTwo()
{
    webBrowser.InvokeScript("fetchBarTwo");
}
```

**MyJavascriptInjector.cs**

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisible(true)]
public class MyJavascriptInjector
{
    public delegate void OnBarOneResponseHandler(string response);
    public delegate void OnBarTwoResponseHandler(string response);
    public event OnBarOneResponseHandler OnBarOneResponse;
    public event OnBarTwoResponseHandler OnBarTwoResponse;

    public void OnBarOneResponse(String response)
    {
        // Called successfully!
        OnBarOneResponse(response);
    }

    public void OnBarTwoResponse(String response)
    {
        // ALSO CALLED SUCCESSFULLY BUT WHEN CALLING THIS Foo.cs event NEVER GETS FIRED.  
        // IT GETS LOST SOMEWHERE BETWEEN HERE and Foo.cs!
        OnBarTwoResponse(response);
    }
}
```

=================

I have an object **Foo** that has two methods on it, **FetchBarOne** and **FetchBarTwo**.

Each method has an event on it, **OnBarOneResponse** and **OnBarTwoResponse**.

The implementing class registers **Foo**'s events in its constructor using the notation "+=" and defines a callback function for each: **foo_OnBarOneResponse(String response)** and **foo_OnBarTwoResponse(String response)**.

**PROBLEM:**

The implementing class observes the following:

1. Calls `this.foo.FetchBarOne();`
2. `foo_OnBarOneResponse(String response)` is fired at a later time.
3. In this callback, implementing class immediately calls `this.foo.FetchBarTwo();`
4. `foo_OnBarTwoResponse(String response)` never fires.

**MORE INFORMATION:**

**Foo** has wrapped [WebBrowser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and is calling [InvokeScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.invokescript(v=vs.110).aspx) to execute javascript in the loaded webpage.  This webpage has many javascript functions on it, including **FetchBarOne** and **FetchBarTwo** on it.  When debugging, **FetchBarTwo** is called and it successfully responds with data.  However, after *WebBrowser* returns the data successfully, when **Foo** calls its internal **OnBarTwoResponseHandler** event delegate that was registered by the implementing class, it gets "lost" somewhere in between - even though it is not null at it clearly has a reference to it.

**FAILED ATTEMPTS OF FIXING ISSUE**

1. Implementing class tried using `Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new ThreadStart(() => this.foo.FetchBarTwo()));` to try and call it from the UI thread.  No success.

If anyone has any thoughts on this matter, I would be most grateful.  Thanks!

Comment: 10 lines of code will talk more than the wall of text. I personally can read code more easily than text. I believe folks here agree with me as well.

Comment: Thanks.  Please see my tl;dr edits at the top.

Comment: My eyes, the goggles do nothing.

Comment: You invoke only the  foo.FetchBarOne(); where do you actually raise the second one?

Comment: @Chris It's inside `foo_OnBarOneResponse` in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The `this.foo` *field* is **NOT** the same instance as the `foo` *variable*.

From your example:

```
public Main()
{
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    foo.OnBarOneResponse += foo_OnBarOneResponse;
    foo.OnBarTwoResponse += foo_OnBarTwoResponse;
    foo.FetchBarOne();
}

void foo_OnBarOneResponse(String response)
{
    // Called successfully.
    this.foo.FetchBarTwo();
}
```

Try using your field (which was not included in your example):

```
private Foo foo;

public Main()
{
    this.foo = new Foo();
    this.foo.OnBarOneResponse += foo_OnBarOneResponse;
    this.foo.OnBarTwoResponse += foo_OnBarTwoResponse;
    this.foo.FetchBarOne();
}
```